# Why is user.is_authenticated asserting true after logout

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to write a test for logging out a user in Django. Here is the code:

`urls.py`

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from accounts.views import LoginView, LogoutView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

`views.py`

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.views.generic import View


class LogoutView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

`tests.py`

```py
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class LogoutTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='user1',
            email='user1_123@gmail.com',
            password='top_secret123'
        )

    def test_user_logs_out(self):
        self.client.login(email=self.user.email, password=self.user.password)
        self.assertTrue(self.user.is_authenticated)

        response = self.client.get('/logout/')

        self.assertFalse(self.user.is_authenticated)
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/', 302)
```

The assertion `self.assertFalse(self.user.is_authenticated)` is failing. Testing through the browser seems to work fine. It seems like the user would not be authenticated after calling `logout()`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It seems like the user would not be authenticated after calling `logout()`. Am I missing something?

[**`.is_authenticated`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) does *not* check if a user is logged in. Every real `User` returns *always* `True` for `is_authenticated`. An [**`AnonymousUser`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object) will return `False` for example. If you thus log out, then `request.user` will be the `AnonymousUser`, and thus not be authenticated.

In other words, if you use `request.user.is_authenticated`, you will call this on the logged-in user if the session is bounded to a user (you logged in with the browser), and you call this on the `AnonymousUser` in case the browser did not log in a user/the browser logged out.

Comment: I'd been struggling with this because I didn't realize that `request.user` is `Union[AbstractBaseUser, AnonymousUser]`, very strange to approach this with a "type switcharoo" technique but I'm sure it makes some sense in the grand scheme of things.